# Desktop and Launch Bar gone

Tags: unity

On Toshiba Satellite L300 running Ubuntu 14.04 for no obvious reason the desktop has vanished and using the mouse reveals 4 Untitled Folders which are empty. There is no Launch bar. Have tried various things from forums - what do I do next?

Comment: tried sudo get-apt install ubuntu-desktop but no change other than top bar including wifi indicator and calendar and on/off has re-appeared. Still no launcher

Comment: also tried unity --replace - get error message: X10:  Fatal IO error 9 (Bad file descriptor) on X server ":0"

Comment: tried (from Ubuntu handbook) dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ and got: error: cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Answer (score 0):

After much trawling through various posts on Ask Ubuntu, etc. I finally found the following worked:

If unity still does not load try:
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons &disown

I now have the Unity launcher sidebar back and can use the laptop again.
Hoo*******ray!